# switch the double integral and evaluate it.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm considering
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{x^2}1dydx
$$

[image]

[image]

Sketch the region in the plane whose area is given by the double integral.
Switch the order of integration and evaluate the resulting iterated integral.

Comment: You can do it directly without switching. Can you evaluate $\int_0^{x^2}1dy$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The region whose area is given by $$\int_0^2\int_0^{x^2}1dydx=\int_0^2x^2dx=\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|_{0}^2=\frac{8}{3}$$
 is shown below:
[image]

Switching the order of integration, we get
$$\int_0^4\int_\sqrt{y}^21dxdy=\int_0^4\big[2-\sqrt{y}\big]dy=\bigg[2y-\frac{2y^{3/2}}{3}\bigg]_0^4=8-\frac{16}{3}=\frac{8}{3}.$$

where the region is given below
[image]